# Restarting named container assigns different IP

Tags: linux, networking, docker, linux-containers

Im a trying to deploy my application using Docker and came across an issue that restarting named containers assigns a different IP to container. Maybe explaining what I am doing will better explain the issue:

- Postgres runs inside a separate container named `"postgres"`
  `$ PG_ID=$(docker run --name postgres postgres/image)`
- My webapp container links to postgres container
  `$ APP_ID=$(docker run --link postgres:postgres webapp/image)`

Linking postgres container image to webapp container inserts in webapp container a hosts file entry with the IP of the postgres container. This allows me to point to postgres db  within my webapp using `postgres:5432` (I am using Django btw). This all works well except if for some reason postgres crashes.

Before I manually stop postgres process to simulate postgres process crashing I verify IP of postgres container:

```
$ docker inspect --format "{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}" $PG_ID
172.17.0.73
```

Now to simulate crash I stop postgres container:

```
$ docker stop $PG_ID
```

If now I restart postgres by using

```
$ docker start $PG_ID
```

the ip of the container changes:

```
$ docker inspect --format "{{.NetworkSettings.IPAddress}}" $PG_ID
172.17.0.74
```

Therefore the IP which points to postgres container in webapp container is no longer correct. I though that by naming container docker assigns a name to it with specific configs so that you can reliably link between containers (both network and volumes). If the IP changes this seems to defeat the purpose.

If I have to restart my webapp process each time I postgres restarts, this does not seem any better than just using a single container to run both processes. Then I can use supervisor or something similar to keep both of them running and use `localhost` to link between processes.

I am still new to Docker so am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in docker?

Comment: You may find this [related question & answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252598/how-to-setup-linkage-between-docker-containers-so-that-restarting-wont-break-it) useful.

Comment: thanks. will take a look at ddns. hopefully wont be that difficult. Docker seems very cool however it seems needs some learning curve to use it properly...

Answer (score 0):

2nd UPDATE: maybe you already discovered this, but as workaround, I plan to map the service to share the database to the host interface (ej: with -p 5432:5432), and connect the webapps to the host IP (the IP of the docker0 interface: in my Ubuntu and CentOS, the IP is 172.17.42.1). If you restart the postgres container, the conteiner's IP will change, but I wil be accesible using 172.17.42.1:5432. The downside is that you are exposing that port to all the containers, and loose the fine-grained mapping that --link gives you.

--- OLD UPDATES:

CORRECTION: Docker will map 'postgres' to the container's IP in the /etc/hosts files, on the webapp container. So, in the webapp container, you can ping 'postgres', and it will be mapped to the IP.

1st UPDATE: I've seen that Docker generates and mounts /etc/hosts, /etc/resolv.conf, etc. to have always the correct information, but this does not apply when the linked container is restarted. So, I've assumed (wrongly) that Docker would update the hosts files.

-- ORIGINAL (wrong) response:

Add --hostname=postgres-db (you can use anythin, I'm using something different than 'postgres' to avoid confussion with the container name):

```
$ docker run --name postgres --hostname postgres-db postgres/image
```

Docker will map 'postgres-db' to the container's IP (check the contents of /etc/hosts on the webapp container).

This will allow you run 'ping postgres-db' from the webapp container. If the IP changes, Dockers will update /etc/hosts for you.

In the Django app, use 'postgres-db' instead of the IP (or whatever you use for --hostname of the container with PostgreSql).

Bye!
Horacio

Comment: please check your facts. Docker when linking container only uses `--name` parameter. `--hostname` is only used to insert an entry in the `postgres` container, not in the `webapp`container.

Comment: miki725: you are right, I get confused in my tests. I have used the same string for name and hostname, and assumed that the specified in 'hostname' were used in /etc/hosts...

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/, it should be possible to assign a static IP for your container -- at the time of container creation -- using the `--ip` option:

Example:

```
docker run -itd --ip 172.30.100.104 --name postgres postgres/image
```

....where 172.30.100.104 is a free IP address on a custom bridge/overlay network.

This should then retain the same IP address even if postgres container crashes/restarts.

Looks like this was released in Docker Engine v 1.10 or greater, therefore if you have a lower version, you have to upgrade first.

Answer (score -1):

As of Docker 1.0 they implemented a stronger sense of linked containers. Now you can use the container instance name as if it were the host name.

Here is a [link](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/)

I found a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252598/how-to-setup-linkage-between-docker-containers-so-that-restarting-wont-break-it) that better describes your problem. And while that question was answered I wonder whether or not this [ambassador](https://docs.docker.com/articles/ambassador_pattern_linking/) pattern might not solve the problem... this assumes that the ambassador is more reliable than the services that link.

Comment: please read my question. once the parent container is restarted, its IP changes hence whatever is in the hosts file is no longer valid.