# Ran docker container `--restart always` rebooted server, container/image did not restart

Tags: docker

```
docker run \
    -d \
    -e "SOME_ENV_VAR=someValue" \
    -h some.host.com \
    --link db-thing:db \
    --name someName \
    -p 5555:5555 \
    --restart always \
    -v /someFile:/otherFile:ro \
    -v /someDir/:/otherDir/ \
    web-thing
```

I'm using docker 1.7.1 on CentOS.  I started some containers with `--restart always`, then rebooted the server.  Docker came back up, but none of the containers/images restarted.  I thought they might depend on each other, so restarted the `db-thing` image, but even then the others still didn't restart.  What could keep the containers from restarting?

Does this have anything to do with this: [How to setup linkage between docker containers so that restarting won't break it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24252598/how-to-setup-linkage-between-docker-containers-so-that-restarting-wont-break-it)

Answer (score 1):

I tried again and it worked.  Doh!  My best guess is that I was developing my docker commands in a file (to check into source control) and I must have forgotten to run the version of the command that had `--restart always`.  Embarrassing!